# Highest Columns Number Records Issue

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, numeric-data

Highest Columns Number Records Issue

I have a `test.txt` file with contents as follows:

```
1:2:3
123:5
34589:5:0
34567:8:7
781:9:09
```

Could you please help me getting the following output from that `test.txt` file?

```
345895:0
345678:7
7819:09
```

Explanation: below line contains the highest number column i,g. 3 and removed :

```
345895:0
345678:7
7819:09
```

Comment: do u want to print if the first column is more than 3 digits?

Comment: records should be 2 column always. need to replace the those having more than 2 columns . thats it

Comment: @RabindraPanigrahi are you looking for something like: `awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} NR>=3 { print $1,$3 }' yourfile` ?

Comment: `1:2:3` has 3 columns too, so shouldn't `12:3` appear in the output as well?

Comment: Do you need to sort numbers by the first column and print the highest three? Why is the 781:9:09 converted to 7819:09? Do you compare numbers before this concatenation or after?

Comment: Seams u want to merge all columns except last...am i right?

Comment: @DonHolgo you are correct, I missed that bit: `awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} NR>1 { if(NF>=3) print $1,$3}' filename`  or the shorter version: `awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} NR>1 && NF>=3 { print $1,$3}' filename`

Comment: @ValentinBajrami in OPs expected result he concatenated the column 1 and 2 in the three-column line.

Comment: @RabindraPanigrahi `sort -nrk1 test.txt | head -n3 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {print $1$2,$3}'`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the following:

Assume that your file is called `test.txt`

```bsh
cat test.txt | sort -nr | head -n 3 | sed 's/://'
```

Assume that the file content is the following:

```
1:2:3
123:5
34589:5:0
34567:8:7
781:9:09
```

The result will be the following:

```
345895:0
345678:7
781:9:09
```

#### Explaination

---

- `cat test.txt` -> Simply print the content of the file to the stdout
- `sort -nr` -> Sort the data assuming that are `number` symbol (**-n**), in reverse order (**-r**)
- `head -n3` -> Filter from the result, only the first `3` lines (**-n 3**)
- `sed 's/://'` -> Remove the first `:` occurrence

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood the requirements correctly, this should work:

`awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"} NF > 2 {print $1$2,$3}' test.txt`

This prints all lines with more than two columns, concatenating the first two into one.